# Difference between "social" and "societal"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, terminology, sociolinguistics

What's the difference between *social* and *societal*? Are they perfectly synonymous? If not, what is the difference in nuance?

The relevant definition of [social](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/social) reads:

> *relating to society or its organization*

The only definition of [societal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/societal) is:

> *relating to society or social relations*

[NGrams suggests](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=societal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) that the word had its origins in the early 20th century and gained in popularity after the 1950s. Why did the use of *societal* crop up? Was it perhaps it is the more obvious and natural adjective of *society*? If it is used to disambiguate or distance away from certain connotations of *social*, what are they?

According to COCA, *societal*, while largely used in academia, also sees significant use in magazines and newspapers. It also convincingly outscores *social* when collocated with terms such as *shift* and *estrangement*. On the other hand, the use of *societal worker*, *societal service*, *societal justice* etc., do not register on COCA's scales.

Answer (score 8):

*Social* has over 500M hits in [NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=social,societal&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), as opposed to only 7M for the more recent *societal*. So the main difference is OP probably always wants to use the former, because that's the standard word and it covers *all* meanings.

*Societal* is the more recent word for *of [human] society*, which is its *only* meaning. It's primarily used in academic writing, so OP is unlikely to need it.

Comment: Nonetheless, if there's any confusion, "societal" allows you to disambiguate-- it is probably for this reason that it is reasonably common in academic writing.

Comment: According to etymonline, _social_ (in the concerned sense) was first recorded in 1695 and _societal_ in 1898, so for 200 years _social_ managed to go by its given name, before someone donned it with a nickname. One need use _societal_ only where ambiguity truly might arise, and those situations are rare. The sociologists I've read all use _social_ with no second thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

### Societal

It appears "societal" was primarily limited to academic circles in the early 20th century and seems to have been popularized by social scientists in the late 1950's.  The first use I could find was in the book [***Societal** Evolution: A Study of the Evolutionary Basis of the Science of Society* by Albert Galloway Keller](https://books.google.com/books?id=tGACAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA158&dq=%22societal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmxbvds9LTAhUU62MKHe-ZAkUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22societal%22&f=false), which has a copyright date of **1915**.

*The Panama Daily News* in **1957** wrote an analysis of the book *Citadel, Market, and Altar: Emerging Society, Outline of Socionomy, the New Natural Science of Society* by philosopher and social thinker [Spencer Heath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Heath), and appears to credit him with coining the term "societal," though that is likely a misattribution by the journalist, since the term had already appeared earlier.

[R.C. Hoiles "Better Jobs," from *The Panama Daily News*, 1957](https://www.newspapers.com/image/6400093/?terms=societal) (paywalled link)

> Mr. Heath ***seems to coin words***, but he has an index in the rear that defines the meaning of these words.
>
> In this chapter he uses the word "**societal**."  He defines it as follows:
>
> "**This differs from the term *social* only in being more specific.  It has reference always to the general organization of a population... whereas *social* often includes any kind of human, or even animal, interrelationship**.

[image: Spencer Heath Interview]

The book in question was [published in 1957](https://books.google.com/books?id=ycUMAQAAIAAJ) as well.  I can't find the index referred to in the newspaper article in actual print.  Since the journalist treats the term as unrecognizable, this seems to fuel the notion that the term was quite rare and academic, but perhaps Heath's book did play a role in popularizing the term as a more specific term for "social" with regard to human society and its structure in particular.

### Social

**Social**, on the other hand, is a much less recent term.  Though it had previously been used to refer to interactions between individuals, [Etymonline attributes](http://Meaning%20%22of%20or%20pertaining%20to%20society%20as%20a%20natural%20condition%20of%20human%20life%22%20first%20attested%201695) offers a separate origin for the term with regard to society:

> Meaning "of or pertaining to society as a natural condition of human life" first attested 1695, in Locke.

The use by John Locke was in reference to the ["Social Contract" theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract) pertaining to the origin of civilization.

> Several families. . . .somehow came to be
> settled in proximity to one another, and formed a
> **social** bond; they needed a general whose conduct
> might defend them against their enemies in war

- [From Two Treatises of Government - Second Treatise](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/locke1689a.pdf)

Although contract theory in this sense had been written about prior to Locke, such as in [Hobbes's Leviathan in 1651](https://socserv2.socsci.mcmaster.ca/econ/ugcm/3ll3/hobbes/Leviathan.pdf), the book never used the word "social."

Comment: You give lots of info about societal. What about social and how does it differ from social?

Comment: @Mitch I'll have to look into that and add an edit later, I'm about to run out.  Good point though.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I already was dizzy from looking at too many answers about this, until I stumbled here in these forums I like. By then I had my mind made up, on what i already knew... So my nearly definitive stance on this is...

*Societal* relates to the spontaneous and/or directed structuration and organization of society as a whole, while *Social* refers *mostly* to the relations of persons or groups within society.

So *societal* was probably created and used to specify this holistic approach [which at long last is percolating into people's view]. Until then *social* would have sufficed.

Comment: This does fit with my experience: humans are *social* animals, not *societal* animals

Answer (score 1):

I think social stands for inter-relationship whereas, societal stands more for collective tendency.